# Как убрать цену при подписке?

Tags: woocommerce

Есть задача, сделать подписку на товары.

Если клиент не покупает подписку, то расплачивается за товары по стандартной цене. Если оформляет подписку, то у товара удаляется цена и клиент складывает в корзину товар без цены, а далее платит только за доставку.

Как вариант, в качестве костыля, цену можно не убирать, а делать скидку в 100%.

Если ставить плагин подписки, но можно ли как-то в дальнейшем убирать цену? И может быть кто-нибудь знает плагин, где это можно сделать автоматом?

Comment: Спасибо за просмотры, ответ нашелся самостоятельно. Просто совсем забыл о ролях пользователей. Задачу можно решить таким плагином, как "WC Role Based Price".